# CSS background image svg

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design

I'm trying to use an svg image for my background image in CSS. The image is only rescaling in larger devices, it remains constant in devices with width and height smaller that the svg image size.

Here's my code :

```
body {
  background-image: url(svgImg.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Can you help me make the image redimension on every screen ?

Comment: it's an svg file actually

Comment: Here: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19683628/2195551

Comment: solved like this : background-image: url(svgImg.svg) ;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color:#464646;
  background-size: cover;

Comment: @AlexandruSerban post it as an answer then or edit your question

Answer (score 1):

This code made it do it, it can be written in one single line, but i'm posting every detail so it would be explanatory.

```
body{
background-image: url(svgImg.svg) ;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color:#464646;
background-size: cover; }
```